# How to return a list of numbers of the power of 2?

Tags: python

```
def problem(n):
myList = []
for j in range(0, n):
    number = 2 ** j
    myList.append(number)
return myList
```

I want this code to return the powers of 2 based upon the first n powers of 2. So for example, if I enter in 4, I want it to return [2,4,6,8,16]. Right now, the code returns [1,2,4,8] if I enter in 4. I think it's my range that's messing up the code.

Comment: I don't think you want it to return `[2,4,6,8,16]` as `6` isn't a power of 2.

Answer (score 13):

just use `range(1,n+1)` and it should all work out.  `range` is a little confusing for some because it does not include the endpoint.  So, `range(3)` returns the list `[0,1,2]` and `range(1,3)` returns `[1,2]`.

---

As a side note, simple loops of the form:

```
out = []
for x in ...:
   out.append(...)
```

should typically be replaced by list comprehensions:

```
out = [ 2**j for j in range(1,n+1) ]
```

Comment: That almost does it, it just returns the list of [1,2,4,6,8,16]. And I want it to just return [2,4,6,8,16]. In other words, starting at 2.

Comment: Should it not be `range(1, n+1)`? He does not want it to include `4**0`.

Comment: @Eric -- Thanks.  I didn't look closely enough at that stuff.

Comment: Yep, that it. I just figured it out. Thanks guys!

Comment: You have an off-by-one error since the for loop starts with a zero, not a 1. By starting with a zero, the power of any number using a zero is one. mgilson and Erics code will return the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @Matt -- Phew!  I thought you were saying that my code had an off by one error.  I'm glad it doesn't (I hate those bugs).

Answer (score 7):

Yet another simple and efficient solution (every step in O(1)) without the power operator:

```
def problem(n):
    return [1 << i for i in range(n)]
```

The 1 << i operations is a bitwise operation which translates to 2 ^ i for i integer positive.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do every step in O(1):

```
def gen(x):
   i = 2
   for n in range(x + 1):
       yield i
       i <<= 1

>>> list(gen(4))
[2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
```

PS: There's a typo in the question and if you want 4 numbers for `gen(4)`, use `range(x)` instead

Comment: Oh clever power of 2 bit tricks -- although to be consistent with OP's API, don't you want `range(x)`?  (`gen(4)` returns 4 numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

As @JBernardo pointed out, I assume there is a typo in your question.

```
def squares(n):
    power = n
    square_list = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        square_list.append(2 ** i)
    return square_list


print squares(4)
```

will return

[2,4,8,16]

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
n = input()
a = [i for i in xrange(2, n+1) if (math.log(i)/math.log(2)).is_integer()]
print a
>>> [2, 4, 8, 16 ...]
```

Returns list of powers of 2 less than or equal to n

**Explanation:**
A number can only be a power of 2 if its log divided by the log of 2 is an integer.

eg. log(32) = log(2^5) = 5 * log(2)
5 * log(2) when divided by log(2) gives 5 which is an integer.

Also there will be floor(math.log(n, 2)) elements in the list, as that is the formula for the number of powers of 2 below n if n itself is not a power of 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use map:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def power(n):
    return n * n

list(map(power, x))

#output 
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```