# I need a function that start with a positive integer(n) and returns a list of powers of 2, starting with 2

Tags: python, list, function, integer, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return a list of numbers of the power of 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354685/how-to-return-a-list-of-numbers-of-the-power-of-2)

All I know is:

```
l = []

for i in range(2, n=2):
    l.append(1**2)

return l
```

I don't need to have an entire equation, I just need to know the basics of how to do an equation like this.

Comment: This is a little ambiguous; are you trying to go from 2 to n? 2 to n^2? Neither?

Comment: Did you mean to do `l.append(i**2)`?

Comment: For instance, using 4 and trying to find a list of 4 to the 2nd power starting with 2 at the beginning of the list.                                                                  EX: [2,4,8,16] should be the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def powers(n):
    return [2**i for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

([more info](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

Here's the same way, but using a for loop:

```
def powers(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        l.append(2**i)
    return l
```

The code snippit you posted above didn't work for the following reasons:

- You did `l.append(1**2)` -- that's one to the second power, which will always equal one. You probably meant to do `l.append(2**i)`, which is 2 to the power of the variable `i`
- You started your range with 2, but you want to start with 1 so that the first term in your list is 2, not 4.
- You used range incorrectly. There are several ways to do range

  > range(stop) # Start defaults to 0
  >   range(start, stop)
  >   range(start, stop, step) # If unspecified, step defaults to 1

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
def get_powered_vals(endVal):
    return [2**val for val in xrange(endVal+1)]

get_powered_vals(4)
>>> [2,4,8,16]
```

Or without list comprehension:

```
def get_powered_vals(endVal):
    vals = []
    for val in xrange(endVal+1):
        vals.append(2**val)
        print val, vals[-1]
    return vals

get_powered_vals(4)
>>> 1, 2
>>> 2, 4
>>> 3, 8
>>> 4, 16   
>>> [2,4,8,16]
```

Comment: While a list comp is probably the way to do this, you might want to show an explicit loop with a list.append.  If OP doesn't understand that, then a list-comp might be asking a little too much.

Comment: I'll try these out, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all that inefficient exponentiation, just take the last computed value and multiply it by 2.

As a function:

```
>>> def powers(n):
...   ret = [1]
...   while len(ret) < n:
...     ret += [ret[-1]*2]
...   return ret
...
>>> powers(10)
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
```

As a generator:

```
>>> def gen_powers(n):
...   last = 1
...   while n:
...     yield last
...     last *= 2
...     n -= 1
...
>>> list(gen_powers(10))
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
```

As a code-golf one-liner:

```
reduce(lambda a,b:a+[2*a[-1]],range(10),[1])
```